# Access a UITableView from child class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have two view controllers, `class A` and `class B`. `Class B` is a subclass of `class A`. `Class B` has a `UITableView` defined, and in the parent `class A`, I want to be able to `[table reloadData]`. So I want to access a member variable of `class B`from parent `class A`. I tried doing the whole forward declaration thing but that didn't work out. In `class B`, I put `@class A`. And then in my `class A`, I tried declaring a `class B` object to access the table like this: `B *bView=[B alloc] init]; [bView.table reloadData] //doesn't work, I get error: Receiver B is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist`

So not sure why that's not working, but maybe I shouldnt even be doing it like this. Since its a parent class, is there a better way to access child member variables?

Comment: Why do you want a class to access a member variable in one of its _subclasses_? If class B inherits from class A, than in its declaration you cannot just declare `@class A`; you need to import A's interface.

Comment: How do I import A's interface?

Comment: You need to write `#import "A.h"` instead of `@class A` in B's declaration file (B.h).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent gets no implicit access to its childs member variables. So from A's point of view B is any old object.

If B is a subclass of A then you should be doing this in B.h

```
#import "A.h"

@interface B:A
{
...
}
@property (readwrite,retain) UITableView *table;
```

And if you wish to use B in A then you can do this in "A.h" in case where you want a B member

```
@class B

@interface A:Foo
{
B* bar;
}
```

Or don't bother with the forward declaration if you don't want a B member

In both cases in `A.m`

```
#import "B.h"
```

You can also use #include guards to stop double imports.

```
#ifndef AHEADER_H
#define AHEADER_H

@interface A:Foo
...
@end

#endif
```

No matter how many times you use `#import A.h` it will only get imported once.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to do this. Why not just reload the table in the subclass implementation? You can override Class A's methods in Class B if you want to add some new behaviors to existing code.